# read text file and store into array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have a `.txt` file that contains in which the content of an array is written. But if the program closes, the array's content is of course deleted, because of which I need to read the `.txt` file to "remind" the array of its previous content.

That's my code:

```cpp
#include <fstream>

unsigned short int highscores[11]{0};

int main()
{
    highscores[0] = score;
    std::sort(highscores, highscores + 11);
    std::ofstream outputFile("scores.txt", std::ios::trunc);
    for (short int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
        outputFile << highscores[i] << std::endl;
    }
    outputFile.close();
}
```

and that's my `scores.txt` file:

```
22
15
13
10
5
5
3
1
1
1
```

Any recommendations to this code are also welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You are only writing in a file and not reading. If you close your program and start it again your array will be empty like you said. So if you want to read the files from the file you have written in you have to use

std::ifstream inputFile("scores.txt",std::ios::in);

Then there are many ways how to read the file.
One would be to declare a string:

std::string line;

then using a while loop and getline.

usigned short int highscores[11]{0};
int i=0;
while(getline(inputFile,line)
{
highscores[i]=stoi(line);
// stoi means  string to int. We use that because line is a string but we need the numbers

}

Comment: thanks for your help, but that doesn't seem to work. could you please edit it, so that it does function? maybe also include my code and work with 3 times "`"cpp at the beginning and at the end of your code to make the code more readable

Comment: maybe also see the complete code may help you to give an more exact solution: [repository](https://github.com/BlackVyperStudios/snek/blob/highscore/snake/snake.cpp) in line 332. declarations are in [here](https://github.com/BlackVyperStudios/snek/blob/highscore/snake/snake.hpp)